# Drupal 7 can not get rid of cached site

Tags: php, caching, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to fix an old drupal module that has errors, but I can not get any of my changes to become visible on the site.

We have test server and "real" server. I copied the module (let's call it module A) files from the "real" server to test. Now the page shows OK as long as I have module A folder in modules folder (in Drupal). Now we get to the unexpected part: as long as module folder A  has its  info.xml file intact no changes occur, whenever I change the module, control or callback files.

I have noticed that I can rename or comment out all the files I want as long as info.xml is OK and no changes will occur on the test server site. I have tried clearing all caches, running the .php command to invoke emptying all caches and even cleared Drupal cache tables from database.

Now I have no idea what could cause the module to function this way. Only time I can get the module to crash is when I rename the module A folder or rename the .xml file

What could I do to make it retrieve fresh data from the module, callback and control files?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info>
  <companies>
    <company>
      <id>1</id>
      <laskelma>LK</laskelma>
      <dimension>kp,kl,pr,pl</dimension>
    </company>
    <company>
      <id>2</id>
      <laskelma>LK</laskelma>
      <dimension>kp,pr</dimension>
    </company>
    <company>
      <id>3</id>
      <laskelma>YK</laskelma>
      <dimension>kp,pr</dimension>
    </company>
    <company>
      <id>4</id>
      <laskelma>LK</laskelma>
      <dimension>kp,pr</dimension>
    </company>
  </companies>
  <db_schema>
    <db_table>calendar</db_table>
    <db_table>costs</db_table>
    <db_table>cost_sums</db_table>
    <db_table>earning_mem</db_table>
    <db_table>debit_mem</db_table>
  </db_schema>
  <cache_in_use>0</cache_in_use>
  <version_reskontra>201405081237</version_reskontra>
  <version_smt>201405081237</version_smt>
  <version_smt2>201405070647</version_smt2>
</info>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know if you the website has any server caching? For example if you use a module like memcache for Drupal, clearing the drupal cache or clearing the database tables wouldn't make any difference as it's being cached else where on the server. To clear that you would need to use ssh/command line.

To clear it, connect via SSH and use:

```
telnet localhost 11211
flush_all
quit
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Yes There apparantly was memcache in use. Unfortunately no one thought of telling me that :D

Comment: No probs - I know how it feels. We've all been there. 

If you haven't found it already, I've updated my answer with the ssh code you need to clear it with.